# Папка vendor, extention

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте вот такой вопрос интересует. На сайте есть регистрация от yii2-users. Как работать с этим классом, если он в папке vendor. Как известно ее трогать нельзя.
Допустим я хочу доделать загрузку изображения профиля - стандартной yii2-users ёё нету. Как мне организовать работу? Создать контроллер, который унаследуется от нужного контрола в папке вендор, и дописать код загрузки изображения? Тогда и модель и представление тоже нужно поправлять.
Что в таких ситуациях делают?

Comment: В принципе во многих фреймворках ты должен переопределить в своей локальной области представление, контроллер иногда модель, так же ты можешь использовать обсерверы, тогда придёться переопределить только вивер и добавить поле в модель. Собственно что получаеться, допустим есть какое то действие сохранение юзера, на него ты можешь повесить слушатель и взять нужны тебе данные и завписать в модель. Опять же если обсервер хорошо развит то можно отловить и рендер фабрики которая формируют и прям из него добавить загрузку фотографии.